# Martingales: discrete time Vs continuous time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

suppose that we are given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ with a filtration $(\mathcal F_t)_{t \in \mathcal T}$.
I want to consider two different cases for the index set $\mathcal T$, namely

1. $\mathcal{T}=\mathbb{N}$ (discrete case), and
2. $\mathcal{T}=[0, \infty)$ (continuous case)

In both cases the definition of a martingale reads like this:

> A stochastic process $X=(X_t)_{t \in \mathcal T}$ is called a **martingale** with respect to the filtration $(\mathcal F_t)_{t \in \mathcal T}$ if $X$ is integrable, adapted to $(\mathcal F_t)_{t \in \mathcal T}$ and satisfies the martingale property:
>   \begin{align} 
> \tag{1} \label{1}
> \mathbb{E}[X_t\mid \mathcal F_s] =X_s, \quad \text{for all} \ s\leq t, \ s,t \in \mathcal{T}. 
> \end{align}

Now it is well known that in discrete case $\mathcal{T}=\mathbb{N}$ the martingale property is equivalent to the following:
\begin{align} 
\tag{2} \label{2}
\mathbb{E}[X_{t+1}\mid \mathcal F_t] =X_t, \quad \text{for all} \ t\in \mathcal{T}.
\end{align}
This easily follows with the tower property of conditional expectations.

However in continuous time this does not work anymore: if $\mathcal{T}=[0,\infty)$ then $(\ref{2})$ is strictly weaker than $(\ref{1})$.

**Edit: I changed the index set in (\ref{2})!!**
Here comes my question: do you know an example of a stochastic process $X=(X_t)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$ which is integrable, adapted to a filtration and satisfies $(\ref{2})$ but is **not** a martingale?
I tried to, but didn't get very far.
Thank you.

Comment: If we have the phrase, for all $t\in \mathbb{N}$ in (2), than just take a discrete martingale, and put whatever you want between the point with natural indices.

Comment: If you need a concrete example, take like this. Take $X_{t}$, to be $0$, whenever $t\in \mathbb{N}$, and to be $1$, in all other cases.

Comment: However if you impose some conditions continuity, than these would be a question to think about, more carefully. What do you think?

Comment: @kolobokish, sorry this was a silly mistake, I ment $t \in \mathcal{T}$ in equation (2). Already corrected it.
Concerning the continuity of paths, this is not so important in the first place.

Comment: I thought exactly like that. )).

Comment: Try the continuous process $$X_t=\cos(2\pi t)$$

Comment: nice solution, doesn't even involve randomness :)